# C++ Linear Search Algorithm

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I have been struggling with the output of a linear search algorithm for a bit of time now. I have the function that searches the list and returns the position, either -1 if it is not found, or the numeric value of where the matching number was found. Any suggestions on how to get this to output correctly?

The output needs to search through testList, see if that number is in stdList, and give its position

Number 1 (34) was located in position 15.

Number 2 (74) was not in the file.

Number 3 (56) was not in the file.

Number 4 (103) was located in position 75.

etc.

Here is the main section of code that I am having problems with.

ARRAY_STANDARD is referring to the size of the array stdList.

stdList is the array being compared against

Position is what is being returned by the function `searchList()`

testList is referring to the array that is being compared to stdList

value is the element that we are searching for

```
//Outputs

  if (position == -1)
    cout << "Number " << testCount+1 << "(" <<  testList << ")" << " was not in the file." << endl;
  else
    cout << "Number " << testCount+1 << "(" <<  testList << ")" << " was located in position " << value << endl;
}

int searchList(int stdList [], int numElems, int value)
{
  int index=0;
  int position = -1;
  bool found = false;

  while (index < numElems && !found)
  {
    if (stdList[index] == value)
    {
      found = true;
      position = index;
    }
    index++; 
  }
  return position;
}
```

Comment: Why do you expect this to do anything meaningful if the contents of your loop never use the loop iterator `x`? You could just as well remove the loop and get the same output. Something's is seriously wrong here.

Comment: It is reading through an array, x is just a counter.

Comment: _What_ is reading through the array?  Your loop just evaluates the same `if (position == -1)` statement every time, and does not change the values of any variables other than `x` itself.  There is no code that refers to `stdList` or `searchList()` that you mentioned in the summary, and nothing that updates `testList` or that uses `value`.

Comment: searchList() has been added

Comment: Ok, but what is that `for` loop accomplishing, or trying to accomplish?  I don't think you need it.

Comment: There's no point in adding the searchList() when you are not using it...

Comment: Isn't it necessary for it to loop through the values for output? If not wouldn't it stop at the first iteration of a match?

Comment: @Simsyy : The `while` loop in `searchList()` function loops over the array to find the item.  We're still trying to figure out what you intend the output of this program to be, and why _that_ needs a `for` loop.  Seems like you _just_ need an `if` statement to say whether or not you found what you're looking for.

Comment: Edited description for clarity on output.

Comment: @Simsyy : Ah, ok, so you need to do multiple searches.  Got it.  This also implies you have two arrays:  An array of inputs to search for, and an array you're searching in, correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct. Ok, we were able to figure it out. Little bit of tweaking was all it took. Ill throw in my own solution down below

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have lost a few lines of code in the last edit. What you want to do (pseudo code) is this:

```
for each element in testList:                <<<<< this is the for statement you lost
  position = findElement(element, stdList)   <<<<< this is the function you were not calling
  if(position < 0):
    print "not found"
  else:
    print "found element " element " at position " position
```

Take it away...

Answer (score 0):

You should change your method in following way:

```
int searchList(int stdList [], int numElems, int value)
{
  int index=0;
  while (index < numElems)
  {
    if (stdList[index] == value)
    {
      return index;
    }
    index++; 
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Comment: That is cleaner but not his problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
int searchList(int stdList [], int value)
{
    for(int i = 0, length = sizeof(stdList); i < length; ++i)
    {
        if (stdList[i] == value)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Just posting code without any context or explanation isn't a sufficient answer. I suggest you read over [**how to answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer) and expand it.

Answer (score 0):

Successful output.

```
int results;
for(int i = 0; i < 22; i++)
{
    results = searchList(stdList, ARRAY_STANDARD, testList[i]);
    if (results == -1)
        cout << "Number " << i+1 << "(" << testList[i] << ")" << " was not in the file." << endl;
    else
        cout << "Number " << i+1 << "(" << testList[i] << ")" << " was located in position " << results+1 << endl;
}
```

Comment: Glad you figured it out.